# How to get the $95\%$ Wald test confidence interval for $\theta$?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, wald-test, profile-likelihood

Suppose that iid random samples $X_i$ from a discrete CDF $F(x)$ on $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$ with mean $EX=\theta$. We want to estimate $F(x)$. We consider empirical likelihood for $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i I(X_i\le x)$  where $p_i=P(X=X_i)$, and $p_i\ge 0$, $\sum p_i=1$.

Consider the hypothesis:
$$
H_0: \theta=\theta_0, \, v.s. H_a: \theta\neq \theta_0
$$

The empirical likelihood function is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n P(X=X_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i.
$$

Note that maximum of empirical likelihood is $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$. Then the empirical log-likelihood ratio function is $$\log\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1/n)}=\log\prod_{i=1}^n np_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\log np_i$$

To make inference on $\theta$, the profile likelihood of $\theta$ is
$$
\sup_{p_i, \theta}\{\sum \log np_i: p_i\ge 0, \sum P_i=1, \sum p_i(X_i-\theta)=0\}
$$
and MLE is actually $\hat{p}_i=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\bar{X}_n$.

If we randomly get 100 samples from unknown distribution.

***How to get the 95% Wald test confidence interval for $\theta$?***

For 95% Wald-type confidence, if we know the the log-likelihood function $l(\theta)$ and MLE $\hat{\theta}$. Then the CI is determined by $I(\hat{\theta})=-l''(\hat{\theta})$ and $\hat{\theta}$.

What is $I(\theta)=-l''(\theta)$?

Comment: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2927&context=etd

Comment: *"The empirical likelihood function is $\prod_i^n p_i$"* ... where is the influence of the $X_i$ in this likelihood function?

Comment: $$\log\prod_{i=1}^n np_i$$ why is the log of the likelihood function containing an additional $n$ in the product?

Comment: How is the likelihood independent from observations?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because the used definition of likelihood is unclear. We have for instance the following quote: *"The empirical likelihood function is 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n P(X=X_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i.
$$"* ... which does not include any dependence on the observations (it is just a product of the $p_i$) and is *not* a likelihood function.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Have you heard about empirical likelihood? That is just from the paper   by Art owen https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176347494. I do know why do you think that is unclear....

Comment: @quasAliki it is not a problem that I have never heard of empirical likelihood.

Comment: @quasAliki did you mean that the sample is from a discrete distribution or from a continuous distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's look at the derivation of the maximum likelihood estimators : we want to maximize the log-likelihood function with respect to the parameters $p_i$

$$\log \mathcal{L} = \sum_i \log p_i$$

subject to the constraint $\sum_i p_i = 1$. We can do that by introducing a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$ and solving :

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \left( \sum_i \log p_i - \lambda(\sum_i p_i - 1) \right)= 0 $$

which gives $\hat p_i =  1/\lambda$, and from the constraint we get  $\lambda=n$ so we have $\hat p_i =  1/n$.

Consequently,  the MLE for $\theta = \sum_i p_i x_i $ is

$$\hat \theta = \sum_i \hat p_i x_i = 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i = \langle x \rangle $$

Now the *profile* likelihood for $\theta$ is obtained by maximizing the likelihood while keeping $\theta$ fixed. That is, we have the additional constraint $\sum_i p_i x_i = \theta$. We can similarly do it by adding a second lagrange multiplier and solving :

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \left( \sum_i \log p_i - \lambda_1(\sum_i p_i - 1) -\lambda_2(\sum_i p_i x_i - \theta)\right)= 0 $$

which results in

$$\hat p_i = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + x_i \lambda_2} $$

Where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are determined by the two constraints:

$$ \sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + x_i \lambda_2} = 1 $$
$$ \sum_i \frac{x_i}{\lambda_1 + x_i \lambda_2} = \theta .$$

In general this needs to be solved numerically to obtain  $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ as a function of $\theta$, from which we can get $\hat p_i(\theta)$ and calculate the profile likelihood function

$$l(\theta) = \sum_i \log \hat p_i(\theta) $$

However since we are interested at $l''(\theta)$ only evaluated at $\theta=\hat \theta$ we can calculate it directly : first note that

$$ l''(\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \sum_i \frac{1}{\hat p_i} \frac{\partial \hat p_i}{\partial \theta} = -\sum_i \frac{1}{ \hat p_i^2} (\frac{\partial \hat p_i}{\partial \theta})^2 + \sum_i \frac{1}{\hat p_i} \frac{\partial^2 \hat p_i}{\partial \theta^2}. $$

Recall that $\hat \theta$ is the global maximizer of the likelihood function and therefore $\hat p_i (\hat \theta) = \frac{1}{n}$ is the MLE. The second term vanishes at $\theta=\hat \theta$ because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \frac{\partial^2 \hat p_i}{\partial \theta^2} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \theta^2} \sum_i \hat p_i = 0 $ due to the constraint $\sum p_i = 1$ ,

so we are left with :

$$ -l''(\hat \theta) = n^2 \sum_i (\frac{\partial \hat p_i}{\partial \theta})^2 |_{\theta = \hat \theta} .$$

notice that from the expression we have for $\hat p_i$ (recall that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are functions of $\theta$)

$$ \frac{\partial \hat p_i}{\partial \theta} = -\hat p_i^2(\lambda_1' + x_i \lambda_2')$$

therefore we can write

$$ -l''(\hat \theta) =  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i (\lambda_1'(\hat \theta) + x_i \lambda_2'(\hat \theta))^2 .$$

So we need to evaluate the derivatives of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ at $\hat \theta$. We can do this by taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ of the two constraint equations we have, which results in:

$$ -\sum_i p_i^2 (\lambda_1' + x_i \lambda_2')= 0 $$
$$ -\sum_i p_i^2 x_i (\lambda_1' + x_i \lambda_2')= 1 $$

Now evaluating these equations at  $\theta = \hat \theta$ we get

$$ \hat \lambda_1' + \langle x \rangle \hat \lambda_2' = 0 $$
$$ \langle x \rangle \hat \lambda_1' + \langle x^2 \rangle \hat \lambda_2' = n $$

where I abbreviated $\hat \lambda = \lambda(\hat \theta)$. These are two linear equations that can be easily solved to give

$$ \hat \lambda_1' = -\frac{n\langle x \rangle}{\sigma_x^2}$$
$$ \hat \lambda_2' = \frac{n}{\sigma_x^2}$$

where $\sigma_x^2 = \langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2$.

Finally we can plug this into

$$ -l''(\hat \theta) =  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i (\hat\lambda_1' + x_i \hat\lambda_2')^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_x^4} \sum_i(x_i - \langle x \rangle)^2 = \frac{n}{\sigma_x^2}.$$

Notice that we get exactly the "standard" result, namely it is the same as using the standard deviation of the mean $\sigma_x/\sqrt n$.

Comment: As you can see from the answer, it doesn't depend on the distribution of x (which is assumed unknown), just on the observed standard deviation.

Comment: Yes that's correct!